# React Nested Component not Rendering

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I am new to react and I am trying to build a site to help solidify my theoretical knowledge. I am using Storybook to try and develop each component in isolation and I am trying to use the Atomic Methodology.

I currently have two acomponents, A link component and a list component. I am trying to use both components to build a navigation component. Unfortunately, I cannot get this to work. I can get either of the elements to show up independently, but when I try and use them together I get an empty list.

Here is my link component code

```
//Link Component
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import './Link.scss'

const Link = (props) => {
    
    const { children, href, disabled, ...rest} = props
    return <a href={href} {...props}>{children}</a>

}

Link.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
    disabled: PropTypes.bool,
    href: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}

export default Link
```

Here is my List Component Code

```
//List Component
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

function List(props) {
    const { children, lists:{ordered, classId }} =  props
    const ListType = ordered ? 'ol' : 'ul'

    console.log(props)

    const mapListItems = (listItems) => (
        <ListType>
            {listItems.map((item, index) => (
                <li key={item.id}>
                    {item.text}
                    { item.kids != null && item.kids.length > 0 ? mapListItems(item.kids) : "" }
                </li>
            ))}
        </ListType>
    )

    return mapListItems(children)
}

List.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.any,
    ordered: PropTypes.bool,
    dropdown: PropTypes.bool,
    classId: PropTypes.string,
    handleClick: PropTypes.func
}

export default List
```

Lastly, here is my navigation component

```
import React from 'react'
import Link from '../../atoms/Link'
import List from '../../atoms/List'

function Navigation(props) {

    const { children, lists:{ordered, classId} } = props

    return (
        <List {...props}>
            {children.map(child => (
                <Link {...child}>
                    {child.text}
                </Link>
            ))}
        </List>
    )
}

export default Navigation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Turns out that in the List component, I needed to return the item component in my map function, not item.text (since there is no item.text on the child I am returning from the navigation component)